# CSS Scrolling and Z-index

Tags: html, css, scroll, z-index

I am currently laying out the design to a webpage with a top horizontal bar that has a shadow at the bottom and 2 divs below that are set to overflow:scroll;

Normally it looks like this: https://31.media.tumblr.com/12b6c3f5a3642440010ae86565699d41/tumblr_nfgqskuhsa1tllj9bo1_1280.png

but the left div is covering the shadow part, so I changed the z-index to be -1
which now gives me this: https://31.media.tumblr.com/d18f3476db91b54282d9b0bf8ed08a80/tumblr_nfgqskuhsa1tllj9bo2_1280.png
which is what I want it to look like but then the left div doesn't scroll anymore.

I tried putting positive numbers with z-index of top being 5 and the left z-index to be 4, but it doesn't send the left div to the back.

How can I have the shadow to overlap the left div but have the left div still be scrollable?

Here is my code:

Html:

```
</head>
<body>

<div id="top">
<div id="logo">Baby Steps</div>


</div>


<div id="left">
a<br><br>
a<br><br>
a<br><br>
a<br><br>
a<br><br>
a<br><br>THESE GO ON</div>


<div id="right"</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:
    body
    {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

```
#top{
width: 102%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #41b6c4;
height:60px;    
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px #000;

}


#logo{
color:white;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size:2em;
margin:0.2em;


}


#left{
position: relative;
top: 0px;
height:100%;
width:18%;
background-color:#606061;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: The only reason why z-index wouldn't work in your case is likely due to [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) — which means we need to have a look at your HTML code and CSS. Can you create a test case with a code snippet or a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the z-index of the left div, and remove float from top div. try this

```
body { 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; }

#top{
 position:relative;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #41b6c4;
 height:60px;    
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -3px #000;
}

#logo{
 color:white;
 font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size:2em;
 margin:0.2em;
}

#left{
 position: relative;
 z-index:1;
 height:100%;
 width:18%;
 background-color:#606061;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

example here http://jsfiddle.net/ysu9xhv7/1/